# Facebook Javascript Login 2.0 returning blank screen in Facebook on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app the will sit within Facebook. Here's the "[Link to the application on facebook](https://apps.facebook.com/628899130536460)".

I've implemented the Javascript login v2.0 as per the Quickstart on the Facebook Dev page and it app works perfectly on the desktop and can make calls to the API.

However, if i go to the app on mobile within Facebooks' own iOS app (have to post it in a status and then click on the link) after I click the login button and approve the permissions, I just get a blank screen and don't get returned to my app.

If I go back to my news feed and then return to my app, the login and permissions are recognized and my open graph calls work as per the desktop version.

Is there something that I'm missing for the mobile version? I have tried adding a callbackURL in the FB.init

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{MY-APP-ID}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name);
      document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML =
        'Hi ' + response.first_name + '!';

       document.getElementById('fphoto').src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture';
    });
  }
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="login">
    <h4>Login below to get started</h4>
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
 </div>

 <div>
     <a href="#">
         <img id="fphoto" src="" alt="...">
     </a>
     <div>
         <h4 class="media-heading" id="userName"></h4>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Same problem here. Did you able to get any answer by chance. If yes, plz do post as Answer.